# Why request.getAttribute is returning 'null' String when the value is null?

Tags: java, jsp

Why request.getAttribute is returning 'null' String when the value is null?

It's returning a string of 4 characters (null, n, u, l, l) Why?, I need that the value of the String be "" or null.

Can you help?

```
<%    String queryString = new String(); 
    queryString = request.getAttribute("query");  %>
```

Comment: Because a `"null"` string is been set there instead of `null` literal. In other words, you need to take a step back and doublecheck the code responsible for setting the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
String queryString = new String();

    if (!request.getParameterMap().containsKey("query")) {
        queryString = "";
    }
    else {
        queryString = request.getParameter("query");
    }
```